# ScheduledExecutorService и несколько потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть 2 потока

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable_500ms(), 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable_30min(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Такая запись верна или их нужно разделить по-другому?

Вариант 2

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable_500ms(), 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
ScheduledExecutorService service2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable_30min(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: `есть 2 потока` - не факт. Scheduler сам разберется, два там или один. Или вообще на каждый запуск - свой поток. И лучше 1 вариант

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` - как следует из названия, в таком executor-е только один поток.

То есть, в первом варианте, когда у вас придет время запустить две задачи одновременно, то одна из них будет ждать пока не закончится вторая. Сколько она будет ждать зависит от того, как долго будет выполнятся первая.

Во втором варианте, у вас два таких executor-а, соответственно, обе задачи могут исполнятся одновременно.

Если еще и третий вариант. Создать executor, у которого больше одного рабочего потока:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
```

Ну и использовать его как раньше.

Какой вариант выбирать - это зависит от задачи.
Иногда нужно ограничивать параллелизм, чтобы не перегружать сервер, например, или потому, что задачи работают с каким-то разделяемым ресурсом и не должны работать параллельно. А иногда важно, чтоб задачи использовали ресурсы сервера по максимуму и исполнялись как можно быстрее.

Вот пример, показывающий, что однопоточный executor не может выполнять две задачи одновременно:

```
public class A {

  public static class MyRunnable1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("MyRunnable1 is running");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      System.out.println("MyRunnable1 finished");
    }

  }

  public static class MyRunnable2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("MyRunnable2 is running");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      System.out.println("MyRunnable2 finished");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable1(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable2(), 0, 400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

И результат выполнения:

[image: Выполнение executor-а с одним потоком]